# Resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present working in graph explorer but not in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I try to get licence details using [https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users/{mail}/licenseDetails](https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users/%7Bmail%7D/licenseDetails) endpoint. when I run the above endpoint in graph explorer, it works fine and gives me a proper response like the one below.

[image]

but when I try to run the above endpoint in my laravel application it gives me

```
{"error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource 'divyesh@xxxxxxxx.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.","innerError":{"date":"2023-04-12T06:02:36","request-id":"f3edf53c-d432-4ddb-9611-aa96482e4ae6","client-request-id":"f3edf53c-d432-4ddb-9611-aa96482e4ae6"}}}
```

this is my code

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($this->graph_auth());

try{
    $user_mail = $request['semail'];
    $licenses = $graph->setApiVersion("V1.0")
                      ->createRequest("GET", "/users/".$user_mail."/licenseDetails")
                      ->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e){
    info($e);
}
```

and graph_auth is

```
public function graph_auth() {
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.env("TANANT_ID").'/oauth2/token?api-version=beta';
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => env("CLIENT_ID"),
            'client_secret' => env("CLIENT_SECRET"),
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'scope' => 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/7b2cd291-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2b920c07e5f7',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
    return $token->access_token;
}
```

I am using https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php package to call Microsoft api

Comment: Does your laravel app use delegated or application permissions? In Graph Explorer you are using delegated permissions. Also the scope seems to me weird. Any reason why do not use scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default?

Comment: laravel app uses application permission, whatever permissions on graph explorer, I gave it on both delegated and application. I also used default scope but not any success